# Error when using pointers to append into slice [][]int

Tags: go, powerset

While I was trying to solve a problem "[Subset II](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/august-leetcoding-challenge-2021/613/week-1-august-1st-august-7th/3837/)" from LC, I came across a strange problem. The code generates a power set from a given set.
However, when I run the code it failed because one of the set wasn't correct.

The set [0,3,5,7] replaced by [0,3,5,9] (hence gets appended twice).

I have a print statement (highlighted in code) right before a set gets appended to res, and it prints the correct power set.

The only issue I could think is the use of pointers to append values into a slice, however since it's does not run concurrently I don't see why there would be a race condition.
Appreciate if someone can point out my mistake.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func ValueCount( nums []int) map[int]int{
  hm := make(map[int]int)
  for _,v := range(nums){
    if c, ok := hm[v]; ok {
      hm[v] = c + 1
    }else{
      hm[v] = 1
    }
  }
  return hm
}

func subsetsWithDup(nums []int) [][]int {
    var res [][]int
    res = append(res,[]int{})
    sort.Ints(nums)
  hashMap := ValueCount(nums)
  var t []int
  printTest(nums, t, &res, hashMap)
    return res
}


func printTest(nums []int, t []int, res *[][]int, hm map[int]int) {
  if len(nums) == 0 {
    return
  }
  for i:= 0; i < len(nums); {
    v := nums[i]
    x := nums[i:]
    for  k:= 0; k< hm[v]; k++ {
      var a,b []int
      for z:= 0; z<k+1; z++ { 
        a = append(t,x[z])
      }
      fmt.Println(a) // <--------- Prints the values that gets appended to res
      *res = append(*res, a)    
      b = a
      printTest(nums[i+hm[v]:], b, res, hm)
    }
    i += hm[v]
  }
  
}

func main(){
    n := []int{9,0,3,5,7}
    fmt.Println("Find the power set of:", n)
    fmt.Println(subsetsWithDup(n))
}

// [0,3,5,7] changes to 
// [0,3,5,9] in the output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug occurs on line 40:

```golang
a = append(t, x[z])
```

A quick fix would be to change this `for` loop:

```golang
        for k := 0; k < hm[v]; k++ {
            var a, b []int
            for z := 0; z < k+1; z++ {
                a = append(t, x[z])
            }
            fmt.Println(a) // <--------- Prints the values that gets appended to res
            *res = append(*res, a)
            b = a
            printTest(nums[i+hm[v]:], b, res, hm)
        }
```

To this:

```golang
        for k := 0; k < hm[v]; k++ {
            var a, b []int
            a = make([]int, len(t))
            copy(a, t)
            for z := 0; z < k+1; z++ {
                a = append(a, x[z])
            }
            fmt.Println(a) // <--------- Prints the values that gets appended to res
            *res = append(*res, a)
            b = a
            printTest(nums[i+hm[v]:], b, res, hm)
        }
```

It has to do with how Go uses slices as a data structure. When the first argument to the built-in `append` function was a slice argument, it copied some of the slice's internal data that wasn't intuitive to the programmer. It then modified the argument slice, `t`, and the newly created slice, `a`.

I'd recommend reading up on [slice internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) if you're interested in learning more.

Full program edited:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func ValueCount(nums []int) map[int]int {
    hm := make(map[int]int)
    for _, v := range nums {
        if c, ok := hm[v]; ok {
            hm[v] = c + 1
        } else {
            hm[v] = 1
        }
    }
    return hm
}

func subsetsWithDup(nums []int) [][]int {
    var res [][]int
    res = append(res, []int{})
    sort.Ints(nums)
    hashMap := ValueCount(nums)
    var t []int
    printTest(nums, t, &res, hashMap)
    return res
}

func printTest(nums []int, t []int, res *[][]int, hm map[int]int) {
    if len(nums) == 0 {
        return
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); {
        v := nums[i]
        x := nums[i:]
        for k := 0; k < hm[v]; k++ {
            var a, b []int
            a = make([]int, len(t))
            copy(a, t)
            for z := 0; z < k+1; z++ {
                a = append(a, x[z])
            }
            fmt.Println(a) // <--------- Prints the values that gets appended to res
            *res = append(*res, a)
            b = a
            printTest(nums[i+hm[v]:], b, res, hm)
        }
        i += hm[v]
    }

}

func main() {
    n := []int{9, 0, 3, 5, 7}
    fmt.Println("Find the power set of:", n)
    fmt.Println(subsetsWithDup(n))
}
```

New output:

```
Find the power set of: [9 0 3 5 7]
[0]
[0 3]
[0 3 5]
[0 3 5 7]
[0 3 5 7 9]
[0 3 5 9]
[0 3 7]
[0 3 7 9]
[0 3 9]
[0 5]
[0 5 7]
[0 5 7 9]
[0 5 9]
[0 7]
[0 7 9]
[0 9]
[3]
[3 5]
[3 5 7]
[3 5 7 9]
[3 5 9]
[3 7]
[3 7 9]
[3 9]
[5]
[5 7]
[5 7 9]
[5 9]
[7]
[7 9]
[9]
[[] [0] [0 3] [0 3 5] [0 3 5 7] [0 3 5 7 9] [0 3 5 9] [0 3 7] [0 3 7 9] [0 3 9] [0 5] [0 5 7] [0 5 7 9] [0 5 9] [0 7] [0 7 9] [0 9] [3] [3 5] [3 5 7] [3 5 7 9] [3 5 9] [3 7] [3 7 9] [3 9] [5] [5 7] [5 7 9] [5 9] [7] [7 9] [9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Be ***very careful*** using (and reusing) slice results - especially when altering those slice values later. Since slices have backing arrays, the referenced data can change in [very unexpected ways](https://blog.allegro.tech/2017/07/golang-slices-gotcha.html)!

A quick fix to your problem is to copy slice results to a new slice. This ensures changes to the original slice do not introduce bugs (especially in a recursive algorithm).

To copy a slice:

```
func copyIntSlice(a []int) []int {
    c := make([]int, len(a))
    copy(c, a) // `a` can now grow/shrink/change without affecting `c`
    return c
}
```

and just call this from your main code:

```
aCopy := copyIntSlice(a)
*res = append(*res, aCopy)

printTest(nums[i+hm[v]:], aCopy, res, hm)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1p8Z4sV9foQ